# Powershell, created user, wanted to create mailbox, but cannot find user in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server-2010

I have created a PowerShell script that works great, for most of the times.
First the script creates a user account. Immediately after that, (after a "read-host "does user need to have a mailbox" input) it creates a mailbox. When it's finished doing that, some (Out of Office) settings are applied to the mailbox.

For some reason, it looks like the script is too fast. Quite often it ends in failure, saying that the user cannot be found. It happens just after the mailbox creation part, when I want to apply some settings.
If i wait for some minutes between the user creation and mailbox creation part, things go fine.

**Code**

```
# code here that creates user account.
# read-host "does user need to have a mailbox"?

Enable-Mailbox -identity $sam -database $maildb

# here I get Enable-Mailbox outputs - Name, Alias etc

Get-Mailbox -identity $sam | Set-Mailbox -ExternalOOFOptions InternalOnly
```

Often, I get the error:

> Error: Couldn't find object in OU

I just want the script to create everything without me having to wait.
Is there a way that i can accomplish this ?

I'm running the script from a workstation and am importing the active-directory and exchange PowerShell modules.

Comment: What commands are you using in your script? Maybe it would work better to use the `New-Mailbox` cmdlet. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997663%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx). Just add some logic to delay the creation of the user account and mailbox until after they answer if the account should have a mailbox. If it does, then create it with the `New-Mailbox` command, otherwise use the other method.

Comment: Hi ChadSikorra, thanks for responding !
After the user is created, i'm using: 
Enable-Mailbox -identity $sam -database $maildb
The script gives me some output, like Name, Alias etc. So the mailbox has been created.
After that, the next command is:
Get-Mailbox -identity $sam | Set-Mailbox -ExternalOOFOptions InternalOnly
This is the point where most of the times i get an error like: Error: Couldn't find object in OU

Comment: I think you'd be better off creating the user and mailbox at the same time using the `New-Mailbox` command, which is what it was intended for. That way you won't have to worry about something potentially not syncing right away Only use `New-ADUser` when you're sure they wont have a mailbox. This way you could save output from `New-Mailbox` and call your `Set-Mailbox` command directly against it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Start-Sleep` cmdlet before the cmdlet where you are getting error. Add reasonable delay.

E.g. to add 15 secs delay use:

```
Start-Sleep -s 15
```

More details for this cmdlet here: [Start-Sleep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849939.aspx)

or you can try below code:

```
do
{
    Start-Sleep -s 10
    $mailbox = Get-Mailbox -identity $sam
}
while($mailbox -eq $null)

$mailbox | Set-Mailbox -ExternalOOFOptions InternalOnly
```

Answer (score 0):

These commands can randomly select different domain controllers.
For example:

1. **Enable-Mailbox** (or **New-Mailbox**) command has changed Exchange-attributes of the user object on DC1.
2. **Set-Mailbox** command is trying to change Exchange-attributes of the user object on DC2.
   However, information about the newly created mailbox has not been replicated yet from DC1 to DC2.

You can manually specify the same domain controller for all commands.

```
$DomainController = 'dc1.contoso.com'
$sam = 'username'
New-Mailbox -SamAccountName $sam -DomainController $DomainController ...
Set-Mailbox -Identity $sam -ExternalOOFOptions InternalOnly -DomainController $DomainController ...
```

or

```
$DomainController = 'dc1.contoso.com'
$sam = 'username'
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $sam -Server $DomainController ...
Enable-Mailbox -Identity $sam -DomainController $DomainController ...
Set-Mailbox -Identity $sam -ExternalOOFOptions InternalOnly -DomainController $DomainController ...
```